# Все комбинации символов из алфавита

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Например, дан массив символов `{a, b, c, d, e}` (Может быть различное количество символов). Необходимо реализовать метод, который бы возвращал массив строк всех возможных комбинаций этих символов. Длина комбинаций от 3 до 6 символов включительно. Без равных элементов. Как это сделать?

Comment: комбинациями какой длины?

Comment: @VladD От трёх до шести включительно

Comment: (1) с повторениями или без? (2) внесите это в вопрос тогда

Comment: Изложите свои соображения по этому поводу. Сейчас это выглядит, как просьба сделать домашнее задание за вас.

Comment: До шести невозможно без повторений, раз у вас всего 5 символов.

Comment: Окей, на русском это называется «размещения без повторений», если я не ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужны [размещения без повторений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Их можно сгенерировать, например, так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var chars = new HashSet<char>(new [] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' });
    foreach (var s in GetAllPermutations(chars, 3)) // 3 -- длина
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}

static IEnumerable<string> GetAllPermutations(HashSet<char> chars, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        yield return "";
    foreach (var c in chars.ToList())
    {
        chars.Remove(c);
        foreach (var s in AddAllFrom(chars, n - 1))
            yield return c + s;
        chars.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
abc
abd
acd
acb
adb
adc
bcd
bca
bda
bdc
bac
bad
cda
cdb
cab
cad
cbd
cba
dab
dac
dbc
dba
dca
dcb
```

---

Поскольку функция `GetAllPermutations` возвращает ленивый энумератор, вы можете получить только часть результатов, применив LINQ-операторы наподобие `.Take(10)`. Но моя функция не является чистой: во время энумерации изменяется состояние множества `chars`. (Этот же эффект не даст обходить одну и ту же последовательность дважды *одновременно*.) Для того, чтобы сделать функцию чистой, необходимо инкапсулировать изменяемые данные. Получается следующее:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var chars = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
    var seq = GetAllPermutations(chars, 3).Take(10);
    foreach (var s in seq) // 3 -- длина
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}

static IEnumerable<string> GetAllPermutations(IEnumerable<char> chars, int n)
{
    HashSet<char> curr = new HashSet<char>(chars);
    foreach (var s in GetAllPermutationsRec(n))
        yield return s;
}

static IEnumerable<string> GetAllPermutationsRec(int n, HashSet<char> curr) // not pure!
{
    if (n == 0)
        yield return "";
    foreach (var c in curr.ToList())
    {
        curr.Remove(c);
        foreach (var s in GetAllPermutationsRec(n - 1))
            yield return c + s;
        curr.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Влад, а в данном методе возможно ограничить количество перестановок?

Comment: @UggoFantozzi А что это значит?

Comment: @MBo Метод выводит все возможные перестановки, например,  для n=10, k=5 (n-длина массива символов, k-длина комбинации) их будет 30240, а мне нужно, скажем только 20 из них. Конечно, это 20 можно получить уже после выполнения метода, но у меня с входящими n=10, k=5 метод выполняется 5 секунд.

Comment: Считайте yield-ы, и после нужного количества остановитесь

Comment: @UggoFantozzi: Дополнил ответ

Comment: @MBo: Там была интересная тонкость, пришлось исправить код

Comment: Спасибо! Но у меня ругается на GetAllPermutationsRec (использование переменной перед ее объявлением), пришлось вынести его наружу.  Видимо, я сильно "отстал от жизни")

Comment: @UggoFantozzi: А какая у вас версия языка? Вложенные функции появились в C# 7.0.

Comment: @VladD VS2015 .NET 4.6 С# 6.0
Хотя посмотрел настройки проекта, там указана версия .NET Framework 4.5.2, и судя по всему, выходит, версия языка вообще 5.0.

Comment: @UggoFantozzi: Ого, понятно. Вынес внутреннюю функцию наружу в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо! Сохранил обе версии.