# Реализация алгоритма сочетаний без повторений С#

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Само задание выглядит так:

1. С клавиатуры ввести элементы алфавита, например: a, b, c, d.
2. Задать длину слов N, которые формируются из заданного алфавита.
3. Подсчитать сколько таких слов без повторений букв можно получить.
4. Вывести на экран все возможные слова, которые можем получить из заданного алфавита заданной длины. Например при N=3:
   abc, bcd, cda, dab, …..
   и так далее.

Я реализовала лишь 1-3 пункты, но над 4-м я уже 3 дня думаю. Алгоритмы, которые я пишу, в итоге разрастаются до ужасных размеров с кучей вложенных циклов и метками... Я сдаюсь. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если у вас проблема с вашим кодом - то приведите код.

Comment: Для расчета количества размещений есть формула - ее и используйте.

Comment: [C# алгоритм перебора паролей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/749672/179763)

Comment: Мой код - это одна сплошная проблема. Плюс я написала, что 1-3 пункты сделаны. Формула мною использована. Нужно лишь вывести сами варианты.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я постараюсь проанализировать ответ на этот вопрос!

Comment: Простите, не тот дубликат показал, вот правильный дубликат - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581538/373567

Comment: @aepot, боже, спасибо, оказалось, что это то, что мне нужно! Первый дубликат отлично подошел! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае требуется вывести все **[размещения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)** по `k` из `n` элементов.

Размещения в лексикографическом порядке нетрудно сгенерировать рекурсивно - вставляя на текущую позицию очередной комбинации по очереди все ещё пока неиспользованные элементы (и помечая, что они использованы -  для следующих уровней рекурсии). Результат можно использовать как индексы в наборе введённых символов (`102 => bac` для алфавита `abcd`)

Кода вы не привели, отталкиваться мне не от чего, поэтому пишу, на чём удобнее:

```
const
  n = 5;
  k = 3;
var
  Arrangement: array[0..k-1] of Byte;
  Used: set of Byte;

  procedure GenArrangement(position: Integer);
  var
    i: Byte;
    s: string;
  begin
    if position = k then begin // комбинация заполнена, выводим
      s := '';
      for i := 0 to k-1 do
        s := s + IntToStr(Arrangement[i]);
      Writeln(s);
    end else
      for i := 0 to n - 1 do
        if not(i in Used) then
        begin
          Used := Used + [i];
          Arrangement[position] := i;
          GenArrangement(position + 1);
          Used := Used - [i];
        end;
  end;

begin
  Used := [];
  GenArrangement(0);

012
013
014
021
023
024
031
032
034
041
042
043
102

...
430
431
432
```

Comment: чем это принципиально отличается от [ссылки из комментов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/749672/179763)?

Comment: Я перечитал тот ответ и этот и понял, что моя ссылка вообще не в тему. Старею наверное. Мои извинения.

Comment: @aepot Я не знаю, как правильно ввести и вывести значения на шарпе. А вопрос алгоритмический - вы ведь заметили соответствующий тег?  Тем более ,что языки похожи.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581538/373567